# Is ethernet more efficient than wireless on a Pi

Tags: pi-3, wifi, ethernet, cluster

I'm thinking of building a small Pi cluster using a [Bramble case](https://www.etsy.com/uk/listing/492913299/bramble-case-for-raspberry-pis-made-by?&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=shopping_uk_en_gb_b-electronics_and_accessories-other&utm_custom1=474d754c-1814-4776-b13c-884abe7704dc&gclid=CPOGz-ra4tICFQcQ0wodJ-4ISg) or three, but I'm put off by the hassle of having a mess of Ethernet cables and a large router connecting together 10 or so so small RPis. Given the speed of a Pi3 would Wifi be sufficient to network the cards or would Ethernet be worth the speed bump, assuming I'm running a prototype Spark Cluster using [PiDrives](http://wdlabs.wd.com/category/wd-pidrive/) for storage.

Comment: 10 or so RPis connected to the same AP are certainly able to consume all the bandwidth. It's hard to say whether this will be the case with your application without knowing what application that is.

Comment: The more clients, the more traffic, the more collisions, the more retries on a shared medium with resulting less net bandwidth. I suggest some colored patch cables to have at least an ordered mess. [This case](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/pi-spark-supercomputer/) allows a better air flow than the bramble case.